# Show there is no pair of integers $m,n$ such that $(n-1)^2+n^2+(n+1)^2 = m^3+(m+1)^3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show there is no pair of integers $m,n$ such that $$(n-1)^2+n^2+(n+1)^2 = m^3+(m+1)^3$$

So we have $3n^2 +1= 2m^3+3m^2+3m$. Using modulo 2 we see $n$ must be odd. And using modulo 3 we get $1 \equiv_3 -m^3$. By Fermat little theorem we have $m^3 \equiv_3 m$ so $m= 3l+2$ for some integer $l$. Using modulo 8 we get $m\equiv_4 2$.

Also we have $$3n^2+2 = (2m+1)(m^2+m+1)$$

Since this problem was proposed for 1. grade highscholers I suppose the solution must be easy, but I can not find it. Any idea?

Comment: Well, there is no solution $\pmod 9$,  which is fairly simple to see.  the left hand is either $0, 3\pmod 9$ and the right hand is one of $6,7,8\pmod 9$.

Comment: Oh, should have said:  I rewrote as $3n^2=2m^3+3m^2+3m-1$, when I speak of left and right sides.  My first thought was to isolate $n$ on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

There is no solution $\pmod 9$.  Indeed, expanding both sides and isolating the $n$ on the left we get $$3n^2=2m^3+3m^2+3m-1$$

It is now easy to see that the left hand is one of  $ \{0,3\} \pmod 9$, while the right hand is one of $ \{6,7,8\}\pmod 9$.